# Group PHP array numbers

Tags: php, arrays, numbers, range, grouping

How I can change this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 11
    [8] => 21
    [9] => 22
    [10] => 23
    [11] => 24
)
```

To this:

```
1-7, 11, 21-24
```

I have a list of numbers like this in PHP array, and I just want to make this list a little bit smaller.

```
2000: 3 6 7 11 15 17 25 36 42 43 45
2001: 2 3 4 5 6 9 10 11 12 13 34 37 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52
2002: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 33 34 35 36 37 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52
2003: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51
2004: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 16 17 18 19 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52
2005: 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52
2006: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52
2007: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you realy want, output it ? but anyway, what did you try ?

Comment: Please provide some example code, or what you've tried so far. SO doesn't provide free work.

Comment: I have a list of numbers (like 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 25, 27, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 37, 40, 41, 42, 43, 45, 47, 49, 51, 52), and I just want to make it smaller. And I dont know what to do... <?php $d = false; foreach($numbers AS $key => $value){ if($d){ echo ", "; } echo $value; $d = true; } ?>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting task.

Here's a demo script that does exactly what you want.

Tweak to taste.

**Code**

```
<?php

$groups = array();
$active_group = 0;

$output = array();
$output_counter = 0;

$nums = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 11, 21, 22, 23, 24 );


foreach( $nums as $k => $num ) {

    // if this isn't the first item, and the current number
    // isn't one more than the previous one, increment the counter
    if( $k !== 0 && $nums[$k] !== $nums[$k-1]+1 )
        $active_group ++;

    // add this number to a group
    $groups[ $active_group ][] = $num;

}


// take the 1st and last of each group
foreach( $groups as $group ) {

    $first = array_shift( array_values($group) );
    $output[$output_counter][] = $first;

    $last = array_pop( array_values($group) );
    if( $first !== $last )
        $output[$output_counter][] = $last;

    $output_counter++;

}


echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);

?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 7
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 21
            [1] => 24
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

A single loop will do.  You need need to keep track of the "previous" iteration's value and the "starting" value for storing ranged data.

Code:

```
$prev = -1;                                                    // initialize out of range
foreach ($numbers as $n) {
    if (!isset($start)) {                                      // first iteration
        $start = $n;                                           // declare $start
    } elseif ($n != $prev + 1) {                               // not consecutive
        $result[] = $start == $prev ? $prev : "$start-$prev";  // store single or ranged values
        $start = $n;                                           // update $start
    }
    $prev = $n;                                                // declare / update $prev
}
$result[] = $start == $prev ? $prev : $start . '-' . $prev;    // store final iteration data
echo implode(', ', $result);                                   // comma delimit the values
```

Output from: `$numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 11, 21, 22, 23, 24];` ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/7AOGf))

```
1-7, 11, 21-24
```

Output from: `$numbers = [1, 3, 5, 6, 11, 21, 22, 23, 24, 26];` ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/sp8Eh))

```
1, 3, 5-6, 11, 21-24, 26
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to both compress an array of integers into the string format you want and to expand that string format back out to an array of integers.

```
function compress($expanded) {
    $low = -1;
    $prevNum = -1;
    $expanded = array_unique($expanded);
    sort($expanded, SORT_NUMERIC);
    foreach($expanded as $num) {
        if($low == -1) {
            $low = $num;
        } else if($num - $prevNum > 1) { 
            $compact[] = ($prevNum - $low >= 1) ? sprintf("%d-%d", $low, $prevNum) : $prevNum; 
            $low = $num;
        } 
        $prevNum = $num;
    }
    if($low != -1 ) {
        $compact[] = ($num - $low >= 1) ? sprintf("%d-%d", $low, $num) : $num; 
    }
    return implode(",", $compact);
}

public static function expand($compact) {
    $expanded = Array();
    $compact = explode(",", $compact);
    foreach($compact as $num) {
        if( is_numeric($num) ) {
            $expanded[] = $num;
        } else {
            list($low, $high) = explode("-", $num);
            if( is_numeric($low) && is_numeric($high) && $low < $high) {
                for($i = $low;$i <= $high;$i++) {
                    $expanded[] = $i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $expanded;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
//Placeholder array
$b = array();

// Slice array (where to slice)
$s = array(11, 21);

foreach ($array as $year => $a) {
    for($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++) {
        for($ii = 0; $ii < count($s); $ii++) {
            if($i == 0) {
                $b[$year]['<' . $s[$ii]][] = $a[$i];
                break;
            } else if ( isset($a[$i+1]) && $a[$i] < $s[$ii] && $a[$i+1] >=$s[$ii]){
                $b[$year]['<' . $s[$ii]][] = $a[$i];
                if (isset($s[$ii+1])) {
                    $b[$year]['<' . $s[$ii+1]][] = $a[$i+1];
                } else {
                    $b[$year]['>' . $s[$ii]][] = $a[$i+1];
                }
                break;
            } else if ( !isset($s[$ii+1]) && $i == count($a) - 1) {
                $b[$year]['>' . $s[$ii]][] = $a[$i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**$array**

```
The list of numbers
```

**OUTPUT ($b):**

```
array
  2000 => 
    array
      '<11' => 
        array
          0 => int 3
          1 => int 7
      '<21' => 
        array
          0 => int 11
          1 => int 17
      '>21' => 
        array
          0 => int 25
          1 => int 45
  2001 => 
    array
      '<11' => 
        array
          0 => int 2
          1 => int 10
      '<21' => 
        array
          0 => int 11
          1 => int 13
      '>21' => 
        array
          0 => int 34
          1 => int 52
  2002 => 
    array
      '<11' => 
        array
          0 => int 1
          1 => int 10
      '<21' => 
        array
          0 => int 11
          1 => int 20
      '>21' => 
        array
          0 => int 21
          1 => int 52
  2003 => 
    array
      '<11' => 
        array
          0 => int 1
          1 => int 10
      '<21' => 
        array
          0 => int 11
          1 => int 20
      '>21' => 
        array
          0 => int 21
          1 => int 51
  2004 => 
    array
      '<11' => 
        array
          0 => int 1
          1 => int 10
      '<21' => 
        array
          0 => int 11
          1 => int 19
      '>21' => 
        array
          0 => int 21
          1 => int 52
  2005 => 
    array
      '<11' => 
        array
          0 => int 1
          1 => int 10
      '<21' => 
        array
          0 => int 11
          1 => int 20
      '>21' => 
        array
          0 => int 21
          1 => int 52
  2006 => 
    array
      '<11' => 
        array
          0 => int 1
          1 => int 10
      '<21' => 
        array
          0 => int 11
          1 => int 20
      '>21' => 
        array
          0 => int 21
          1 => int 52
  2007 => 
    array
      '<11' => 
        array
          0 => int 1
          1 => int 10
      '<21' => 
        array
          0 => int 11
          1 => int 20
      '>21' => 
        array
          0 => int 21
          1 => int 52
```

NOTE: Just change the values (11) and (21) to suit your needs. You can add more values.

Comment: This is off topic, but what bugs me lately in SO is the fact that now people down vote an answer without leaving any kind of comment, explaining why the down vote.

Comment: My guess is that the DV is for posting an inflexible answer.  This does not respect the elements in the array when determining the grouping.

Answer (score -5):

Heres an example:

```
$query = "SELECT '1-11' Range, COUNT(rank) rank 
    FROM promoted WHERE rank between 1 and 11 
    union all 
    SELECT '12-21' Range, COUNT(rank) rank 
    from promoted 
    where rank between 12 and 21 
    union all 
    SELECT '22-31' Range, count(rank) rank 
    from promoted 
    where rank between 22 and 31 
    union all 
    SELECT '32-40' Range, count(rank) rank 
    from promoted 
    where rank between 22 and 31 
    union all 
    SELECT rank, count(rank) FROM promoted WHERE rank = '40'";
```

Comment: Assuming these came from a database query?

Comment: How is this going to group the array? All you do is declare a string.